# How to add javascript function to the right element?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a list of elements that display in my page, and they all have different IDs, and all have the same attributes (textboxes, labels).

- Element 0

  - Textbox
  - Textbox
  - Label
- Element 1

  - Textbox
  - Textbox
  - Label
- Element 2

  - Textbox
  - Textbox
  - Label

etc.
My goal here is to detect when user write something in a textbox attribute of the element to display an error message. To achieve that I'm adding an onkeydown javascript function to each of the attributes. For example :
`MyTextbox.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "javascript:OnChangeData();");`

Here is my javascript function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnChangeData() {
        var info = document.getElementById('<%= infoControl.ClientID%>');
        infoDonneePersonnelle.textContent = "Error !.";
    }
</script>
```

Everything works good except the fact that when I write on an attribute of the first element whose Id is 1, my javascript function is triggered with the element of Id 5 (my last element) and display my error message in my last element and not in the first where I wrote.

For summarizing, I have 6 element displayed with attributes, when I write on a textbox of element 1, my javascript function is called but display the error message in my last element no matter if I wrote in the textbox of the first, second or last element.

How can I tell to my function that when I write on a textbox of my first element with ID 0, it should display the error message in my first element with ID 0, not the last one with ID 5.

Comment: you'll need to add more information ... I mean `var info = document.getElementById('<%= infoControl.ClientID%>');` will only ever target one element, because `'<%= infoControl.ClientID%>'` never changes - how do you expect `OnChangeData` to "know" which textbox dispatched the event?

Comment: When my list of elements is loaded, I add the onkeydown function to each of the attributes of each element in a loop. I can't specify anything else than ClientID because it's an ID that is generated by ASP.NET so I don't have the choice.

Comment: I see what you mean @Jaromanda X, maybe my problem is that infoControl.ClientID calls everytime the same ID (here the last one). What could replace ClientID that could call the right asp.net generated ID ?

Comment: nothing - you need to change the code to call the function with an id

Comment: Thank you, I changed the function to call it with an ID and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the way you call `OnChangeData` to pass the element reference. `OnChangeData(this)` passes the reference of the element that triggered the event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnChangeData(element) {
        var parentElement = element.parentElement;
        var infoDonneePersonnelle = parentElement.querySelector('.error-message');

        if (infoDonneePersonnelle) {
            infoDonneePersonnelle.textContent = "Error!";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd handle this using delegated event handling and then relative DOM navigation:

1. Ensure that the overall container of these repeated setups has some way to uniquely identify it on the client at runtime (an ID or a unique class).
2. Within that overall container, ensure that the containers of these repeated setups has a shared class.
3. Use JavaScript to hook the `keydown` (or probably better to use `input`) on the overall container.
4. When the event occurs, find out which container from #2 it happened in via [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) on the event [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).
5. Find the error display element via [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) on the wrapper.

Here's an example. For the purposes of the example, I've made it an error to put a digit in the fields, but that's purely so we can see the error get added and removed:

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("input", (event) => {
    // Find the wrapper that contains this input
    const wrapper = event.target.closest(".wrapper");
    // If we didn't find a wrapper, or the target isn't an input, bail
    if (!wrapper || event.target.tagName !== "INPUT") {
        return;
    }
    
    // Get the value
    const value = event.target.value;
    
    // Find the error element
    const errorElement = wrapper.querySelector(".error");
    
    // Get or clear the message
    if (/\d/.test(value)) { // Just a stand-in for the error condition
        errorElement.textContent = "No digits allowed";
    } else {
        errorElement.textContent = "";
    }
});
```

```css
.error {
    min-height: 1.2rem;
    color: #A00;
}
```

```html
<!-- The overall container; if you don't have one, you can use document.body instead -->
<div id="container">

    <div class="wrapper">
        Element 0
        <div><input type="text"></div>
        <div><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="error"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        Element 1
        <div><input type="text"></div>
        <div><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="error"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        Element 2
        <div><input type="text"></div>
        <div><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="error"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I tried the previous given solution first and it worked for me. Thank you anyway !